# Virtual function does not overrides to latest inheriting object

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

I have 3 classes: **A**, **B**, **C**. **B** inherits from **A**, and **C** inherits from **B** (so **C** is grandchild of **A**).
Every object has function *talk()* that displays text, in **A** and **B** it's virtual.
Let have outside function *call(**A** &a)*, that takes object **A** by reference, and calls function *talk()*.
Sending object **C** to the function, it uses *talk()* from **B** instead of **C**, even that at **B** *talk()* is virtual.
Why it is so? How to make it call version from **C**?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class A {
    public:
        virtual void talk() = 0;
        virtual void say() = 0;
    };

    class B : public A  {
    public:
        virtual void talk() // Why C does not overrides this?
        {   cout << "hello\n";  }   
    };

    class C : public B  {
    public:
        void talk (int a)   // It should override B.talk();
        { cout << "bye\n";}
        virtual void say()  { cout << "my name\n"; }
    };

    void call(A &a) {
        a.talk();   // Why does it call virtual talk() from B rather than from C?
        a.say();    // This was found so it knows about object C
    }

    int main()  {
        C c;
        call(c);
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

I'd expect that *call(A &a)* takes the furthest inheritance version if every class between has *virtual talk()*

Comment: You should always add override to clearly express the intention of overriding a base virtual function. That way compiler will catch the error instead of mysterious failures at runtime in varying flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `C.talk(int)` doesn't override `B.talk()` because `C.talk` takes an int as a parameter, so it's an entirely different function.

You can add `override` after a function declaration to get the compiler to check if it actually overrides anything:

```
class C : public B  {
   public:
    // Here, the compiler complains because there's no talk(int) method
    // That it can override
    void talk (int a) override;
    { cout << "bye\n";}
    virtual void say()  { cout << "my name\n"; }
};
```

Comment: OMG right, I fell so stupid now for missing the parameter :/ Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)